# How to bind a $scope variable with text editor in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my Editor input tag:

```
<textarea cols="18" rows="40" class="wysihtml5 wysihtml5-min form-control" ng-model="TemplateDescription"></textarea>
```

When binding my $scope variable with ng-model then it returns **undefined**. and when I bind my $scope variable with ng-bind-html then still the same result. So then I gave an Id to this textarea and accessed the value inside of it by using this statement.

```
$scope.TemplateDescription = $sce.trustAsHtml($("#templateDescription").val());
```

I get the values as shown in the image below, so how can I get my required html text in my modal so that I can pass this value to save into database. Any kind of help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Can u tell me if your TemplateDescription variable will contain simple text or raw html ? because you have used $sce.trustAsHtml().

Comment: it is containing raw html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your TemplateDescription variable is containing raw HTML then you can try something like this.

First you need to set your raw HTML as trusted.

```
$scope.TemplateDescription = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.TemplateDescription);
```

And then you need to bind `TemplateDescription` using `ng-model`

```
<textarea cols="18" rows="40" class="wysihtml5 wysihtml5-min form-control" ng-model="TemplateDescription"></textarea>
```

I have tested it. It will work.